# What Linux Distrobution would be a good fit for a web developer?

Tags: linux-distributions

I'm **thinking about switching to Linux (again)**. Mainly because miss the bash terminal.

My current server is running Ubuntu and I've used Ubuntu desktop in the past so **I'm not a newbie to linux, but I don't know what distributions are available other than Slackware, Fedora, OpenSUSE, Debian, and its relative Ubuntu.**

I'm looking for:

- **stable** and isn't going to die while I'm coding, or break after the second package update.
- **customizable** without breaking a s**t load of packages.
- **Not bloated** with all sorts of packages and pseudo packages.

If at all possible:

- **for** (web) **programmers**
- **nice looking** user interface
- some sort of **community**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try CentOS - a clone of the RedHat Enterprise Linux.